# Show/hide HTML table row in include file

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a page (Default.aspx) that uses an include file to display left navigation bar content.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder_leftnav" Runat="Server">
    <!--#include file="../../includes/menus/left_nav/menu.htm" -->
</asp:Content>
```

In menu.htm, I have an HTML table. There is one menu item (table row) that I want to display for only certain users, so I have it set to `display:none;`.

In the codebehind of Default.aspx, if the user is in the list of allowed users, I want to change the `display` attribute of that table row, but I can't figure out how to access it. Any ideas? Is there a better way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: user controls are generally used in these circumstances in asp.net. See here for details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e(v=vs.140).aspx

Comment: This question seems to be similar as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/887646/include-html-file-in-c-sharp-code

Comment: I was thinking I might have to convert to that. Thanks @sr28

Comment: Hey, since this is a fix for an existing website I was put on, the answer to that other question worked perfectly and saved me time. Thanks @sr28

Answer (score 0):

A quick way to refactor this may be to convert the menu into a user control that contains a Table control that is easy to manipulate:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc" TagName="Menu" Src="~/Menu.ascx" %>
<asp:Content runat="server" ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder_leftnav">
    <uc:Menu runat="server" id="ucMenu" />
</asp:Content>
```

Menu.ascx replaces menu.htm and would look something like this:

```
<asp:Table ID="tblMenu" runat="server">
    <asp:TableRow ID="trSecured" runat="server">
        <asp:TableCell ID="tdSecured">Secured (Make Hyperlink)</asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
    <asp:TableRow ID="trNonSecured1">
        <asp:TableCell ID="tdNonSecured">Non-Secured (Make Hyperlink)</asp:TableCell>    
    </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
```

Then in your Menu.ascx User Control you can handle the menu display logic:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        'CanViewSecuredPage should be in it's own class so you can share it between menu display
        'logic and for securing the actual page itself (in case they navigate directly by URL).
        If Not CanViewSecuredPage() Then

            Dim tblTable As Table = CType(Me.FindControl("tblMenu"), Table)

            'Or do .FindControl to not be bound to ordinal.
            tblTable.Rows(0).Visible = False

        End If

    End Sub
```